# Highcharts box plot chart customization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

Is it possible to customize the Highcharts box plot chart to have markers instead of boxes. I need to create something that's a cross between a spleen and a box plot. I tried messing with the error bar example but can't get the spline line to be hidden without losing the markers: http://jsfiddle.net/ryfqwska/ I'm trying to create this: [image]

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature vs Rainfall'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                lineWidth: 1
            }
        },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        }],
        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
                format: '{value} °C',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            }
        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value} mm',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],

        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Rainfall error',
            type: 'errorbar',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [[48, 51], [68, 73], [92, 110], [128, 136], [140, 150], [171, 179], [135, 143], [142, 149], [204, 220], [189, 199], [95, 110], [52, 56]],
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '(error range: {point.low}-{point.high} mm)<br/>'
            }
        }, {
            name: 'Temperature',
            type: 'spline',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<span style="font-weight: bold; color: {series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.1f}°C</b> '
            }
        }, {
            name: 'Temperature error',
            type: 'errorbar',
            data: [[6, 8], [5.9, 7.6], [9.4, 10.4], [14.1, 15.9], [18.0, 20.1], [21.0, 24.0], [23.2, 25.3], [26.1, 27.8], [23.2, 23.9], [18.0, 21.1], [12.9, 14.0], [7.6, 10.0]],
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '(error range: {point.low}-{point.high}°C)<br/>'
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your spline series, set the color to 'white' and then set the marker fill color to something else. This will hide the line, show the markers only, and also update the legend correctly.

```
name: 'Temperature',
type: 'spline',
data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
color: 'white', /* hides the line */
marker: { fillColor: 'red'}, /* reveals the markers only */
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<span style="font-weight: bold; color: {series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.1f}°C</b> '
}
```

See also the fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/ryfqwska/1/

I hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I set the color to transparent and that did the trick.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about the transparent setting! I'm glad that worked out for you, and thank you for the improvement.